# Validation loss of CNN lower than training loss but still stuck around 80%

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, conv-neural-network, training-data

I am doing research in NLP and deep learning with mental health textual data. While training my CNN model my validation loss is lower than training loss but almost around the training loss. The validation and training loss does not go too low instead are stuck on almost 75-80% loss but accuracy achieved is also 76%. What shall i do? What is the exact interpretation of this?

Comment: If the model's loss is not decreasing, it means that model is too simple to learn anything new now. So I would advice to increase the complexity of the model if you want to decrease the loss further. But beware, if model becomes too complex you will face overfitting issue.

Additionally, you can try to tune hyperparameters to attain better accuracy while adding more complexity. Start scaling the model slowly.

Comment: Increasing complexity means adding more hidden layers right? so you mean that i should try multiple combinations of hyper parameters and even if then loss doesnt go down i should try to add new layers. Also how many conv units you think is good for text classification using glove embedding?

Comment: You your understanding is correct. First hyperparameter tuning and then more layers. Regarding, number of conv units; I am not sure.